# React Native, flastList is not scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created a flatlist for my list of objects, but I'm facing a problem that it's not scrolling down.
I don't know what's going on. It's simple flatList, is something wrong with flatlist or with my styles? Can please someone help please

here is my code of flatlist, above flat list is just some details about list

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';
import style from '../../styles/commonStyles';
import imagePath from '../../utils/constants/imagePath';
import AppTabButton from '../../components/AppTabButton';
import colors from '../../styles/colors';
import LineSeparator from '../../components/LineSeparator';
import AppButton from '../../components/AppButton';

class Wallet extends Component {
  state = {
    visibleTab: '',
    points: [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: '10% Proifle Completion',
        pts: '1 pt',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Referrals',
        pts: '5 pt',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        text: 'Doctor Service Survey',
        pts: '250 pt',
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        text: 'Doctor Service Survey',
        pts: '250 pt',
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        text: 'Doctor Service Survey',
        pts: '250 pt',
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        text: 'Doctor Service Survey',
        pts: '250 pt',
      },
    ],
    coupons: [
      {
        id: 1,
        icon: imagePath.adi,
        text:
          'Adidas’s gift value packed 50% OFF for every pack. Gift Card lorem epsom.',
        expireDate: '30 Nov 2020',
        colors: colors.red,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        icon: imagePath.nike,
        text:
          'Nike’s gift value packed 50% OFF for every pack. Gift Card lorem epsom.',
        expireDate: '24 Nov 2020',
        colors: colors.orange,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        icon: imagePath.nike,
        text:
          'Nike’s gift value packed 50% OFF for every pack. Gift Card lorem epsom.',
        expireDate: '24 Nov 2020',
        colors: colors.orange,
      },
    ],
    coins: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: '10% Profile Completion',
        coin: '1',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Referrals',
        coin: '5',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Referrals',
        coin: '5',
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Referrals',
        coin: '5',
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Referrals',
        coin: '5',
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        title: 'Referrals',
        coin: '5',
      },
    ],
  };
  showContent = () => {
    if (this.state.visibleTab === 0) {
      return (
        <View>
          <View style={styles.pointContainer}>
            <Text style={[style.fontSize20Semi]}>Total Coins</Text>
            <Image source={imagePath.coin} style={styles.pointIcon} />
            <Text style={[style.fontSize20Semi, styles.points]}>500</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.pointListContainer}>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.coins}
              keyExtractor={(coins) => coins.id.toString()}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                <>
                  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <Image source={imagePath.coin} style={styles.listcoin} />
                    <Text style={[style.fontSize16, styles.font16]}>
                      {item.title}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={[style.fontSize16, styles.font16Point]}>
                      {item.coin}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <LineSeparator style={styles.line} />
                </>
              )}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    } else if (this.state.visibleTab === 1) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.coupon}>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.coupons}
            keyExtractor={(coupons) => coupons.id.toString()}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
              <View style={styles.couponContainer}>
                <View style={[styles.discount, {backgroundColor: item.colors}]}>
                  <Text style={[style.fontSize16Med, styles.font16Med]}>
                    DISCOUNT
                  </Text>
                  <View style={style.circle}></View>
                </View>
                <Image source={item.icon} style={styles.icon} />
                <Text style={[style.fontsize14, styles.font14]}>
                  {item.text}
                </Text>
                <Text style={[style.fontSize14Med, styles.font14Exp]}>
                  Expires
                </Text>
                <Text style={[style.fontSize14, styles.exp]}>
                  {item.expireDate}
                </Text>
                <AppButton
                  color={colors.white}
                  title="Redmee"
                  style={styles.button}
                  textStyle={style.fontSize12}
                />
              </View>
            )}
          />
        </View>
      );
    } else if (this.state.visibleTab === 2) {
      return (
        <View>
          <View style={styles.pointContainer}>
            <Text style={[style.fontSize20Semi]}>Total Points</Text>
            <Image source={imagePath.coin} style={styles.pointIcon} />
            <Text style={[style.fontSize20Semi, styles.points]}>500</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.pointListContainer}>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.points}
              keyExtractor={(points) => points.id.toString()}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                <>
                  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <Image source={imagePath.coin} style={styles.listcoin} />
                    <Text style={[style.fontSize16, styles.font16]}>
                      {item.text}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={[style.fontSize16, styles.font16Point]}>
                      {item.pts}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <LineSeparator style={styles.line} />
                </>
              )}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <Image source={imagePath.logo} style={styles.logo} />
          <Image source={imagePath.bell} style={styles.bell} />
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.profilepicContainer}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}>
            <Image source={imagePath.profilePic} style={styles.profilepic} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <Text style={[style.fontSize30Semi, styles.font30]}>My Wallet</Text>
        <AppTabButton
          style={styles.tabButton}
          data={[{title: 'Cash'}, {title: 'Coupons'}, {title: 'Points'}]}
          onValueChange={(id) => this.setState({visibleTab: id})}
        />
        {this.showContent()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Wallet;
```

and here is styling for flatlist

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
  },
pointContainer: {
    marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(20),
    backgroundColor: '#fef5f5',
    width: '100%',
    height: moderateScaleVertical(51),
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  pointIcon: {
    marginLeft: moderateScale(10),
  },
  points: {
    marginLeft: moderateScale(10),
    color: colors.orange,
  },
  pointListContainer: {
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.23,
    shadowRadius: 2.62,
    elevation: 4,
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    width: moderateScale(363),
    marginLeft: moderateScale(16),
    marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(20),
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  listcoin: {
    marginLeft: moderateScale(16),
    marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(24),
  },
  font16: {
    marginLeft: moderateScale(16),
    marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(24),
  },
  font16Point: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 16,
    color: colors.primary,
    marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(24),
  },
  line: {
    width: moderateScale(331),
    marginLeft: moderateScale(16),
    marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(24),
  },
```

Comment: did you see whole list, or only some first element. your pointListContainer don't have set height.

Comment: yes, I tried to scroll whole list, it don't have height because I don't need it

Comment: well setting height not working

Comment: Try adding zIndex in pointListContainer

Comment: @Kailash still didn't worked

Comment: I create a demo app using your code and it works perfectly if you provide full code of the screen if should helps to find out where is problem

Comment: ya sure wait I Will edit my code

Comment: i edited my question and added my full code check it @DAVID_